# Silverlight - font as an icon rendering is too distorted / pixelated

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight, font-awesome

I currently integrated FontAwesome to my silverlight application. However I noticed that on run time its actually to pixelated

[image]

```
<!-- RadButton (via custom Button) -->
<Style TargetType="controls:Button" x:Key="DefaultRadButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DefaultColorBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="MouseOverStyle" Value="{StaticResource DefaultButtonMouseOverBorder}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusStyle" Value="{StaticResource DefaultButtonFocusBorder}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LineColorBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource OpenSans-Regular}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource CaptureGridRowHeightNumber}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8, 0, 8, 1" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
```

Usage:

```
<controls:Button
    Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}"
    Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">    
    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource RefreshIcon}" Style="{StaticResource FontAwesomeTextBlockStyle}"/>
</controls:Button>
```

Comment: How are you setting your icon? Is it an image?

Comment: It is actually a font rendered to icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently there's a hack around this one

```
<Style x:Key="BaseFontAwesomeTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DefaultColorBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0.001"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `Path` instead of image (if you're using any kind of image). As it's vector path, it should scale based on the parent container and will not have any pixelating issue (also it's faster and uses less resource than image). Sample refresh image,

```
<Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 38,20.5833C 42.9908,20.5833 47.4912,22.6825 50.6667,
      26.046L 50.6667,17.4167L 55.4166,22.1667L 55.4167,34.8333L 42.75,34.8333L 38,30.0833L 46.8512,
      30.0833C 44.6768,27.6539 41.517,26.125 38,26.125C 31.9785,26.125 27.0037,30.6068 26.2296,
      36.4167L 20.6543,36.4167C 21.4543,27.5397 28.9148,20.5833 38,20.5833 Z M 38,49.875C 44.0215,
      49.875 48.9963,45.3932 49.7703,39.5833L 55.3457,39.5833C 54.5457,48.4603 47.0852,55.4167 38,
      55.4167C 33.0092,55.4167 28.5088,53.3175 25.3333,49.954L 25.3333,58.5833L 20.5833,
      53.8333L 20.5833,41.1667L 33.25,41.1667L 38,45.9167L 29.1487,45.9167C 31.3231,48.3461 34.483,
      49.875 38,49.875 Z "/>
```